# HTML select multiple without scrolling and without Ctrl

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a multiple select. The options are populated through an AJAX call. The number of options can vary a lot.

```
<div class="col-md-9">  
    <div class="form-group">
        <select multiple class="commits2 form-control">
            <option>Please select a branch and a tag!</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to have no vertical scroll bar for the select and to show all the options at once on the page. So I am using this css:

```
.commits2{
     overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

As you can see I am using bootstrap. The code that I have renders only the first 4 options in a small container and I can't even scroll further. How can I achieve what I need?

I have also tried:

```
.commits2{
     overflow-y: auto;
}
```

This does not work as it leaves the scroll bar on the right.

I would also like to be able to select multiple options without having to hold ctrl. Here is the bit of jQuery code that is supposed to enable that.

```
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
        return false;
});
```

For some unknown reason I can only click on 2 options and no more if I use this code and if I scroll down the list and press it throws me to the start and doesn't select the option.

Here are the bootstrap includes I am using:

```
<link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<script src = "js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not scroll further because you have set scroll to hidden.

set the `overflow-y` property of `commits2` to `auto`

```
.commits2{
     overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Determine the length of your list items add add it as the size property of your select item. so for example if your ajax call returned 9 items set the `size` property of your `select` to `9`

```
<select multiple class="commits2 form-control" size="9">
```

this makes the select show everything.

You multiselect should work properly as you have it.

```
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
    return false;
});
```

have a look at the following pen:
https://codepen.io/fawmi/pen/RgVRJx

Comment: Setting the select size correctly did the trick, but the jQuerry still doesn't work right, I just can't click on some of the options, I can select some of them but not all.

Comment: have you looked at my pen at https://codepen.io/fawmi/pen/RgVRJx 
I have tested it, it worked fine

Comment: Yes I have seen that in your pen everything works as intended, I can't understand why I am getting the strange behavior I have explained...

Comment: have you got an error on your console? are scripts rendered in proper order.
After that you can help yourself